# Deploying c# app - user need to install .net framework?

Tags: c#, java, .net, frameworks, cross-platform

Hey guys - I just wrote an app using c# and ready to deploy it. Never deployed a c# app before.

I deployed it and VC# outputted a .application file, application folder, and an installer. One of my users ran the installer (Windows 7) and was prompted to download/install the .net framework - which took upwards of 10 minutes. This is not acceptable for how simple my app is.

Moreover, I will need this app to be able to run on mac osx and linux if possible. Should I have wrote this in Java instead (poor planning on my part). What are my options?

Comment: Java is similar to .NET in that the user would have to download the JRE in order to run your Java application. Either option would work fine. Look up Mono for running .NET on OSX and Linux.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. Learned a lot. My question is, how do I distribute my application with an older version of the framework so that more users don't need to install a new .net version? I am using VC# 2010

Comment: Change the target framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: In VS2010, you probably targeted .NET 4.0.  If you didn't use an v4-specific features, you could change your program's target framework to 3.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# is compiled to bytecode that runs on the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), the virtual machine that's at the core of the .NET framework. So yes, you need the .NET framework to run that.

Most current versions of Windows (XP, Vista, 7, etc.) come with some version of the .NET framework pre-installed, so your users don't have to download and install it. However, you might have used a version that's not already installed on the computers of (some of) your users.

For Linux and Mac OS X there is [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)), which is an open source implementation of .NET, but it does not contain everything that Microsoft's .NET contains, so your program might not work fully on Mono.

Using Java is not a real solution in the sense that your users would need to download and install the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) to run Java programs, very similar to the .NET framework. An advantage if you'd have used Java, is that Java is much more cross-platform compatible than .NET (Microsoft has no real interest in making .NET run on anything else than Windows).

Comment: Is there any reason why a user with windows 7 does not have the framework installed? How do I know which version I am using? Can I change the .net framework to an older version for more compatibility?

Comment: @whydna you can find that info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework - in Windows 7, .NET 3.5 is the default.

Comment: You're best off distributing the .NET framework with your app. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows XP does not come with the .NET Framework, nor do any of its service packs. Windows Vista comes with .NET 3.0, and Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

.NET apps require the .NET framework. Java apps require the JRE. Your app is simple because .NET has done a lot of the work for you. A lot of companies write desktop apps in C++, but you will have to be mindful of cross-platform issues.

Comment: What are my options for cross platform compatibility now that I have written the app in c#?

Comment: Your best bet for cross-platform C# is to use Mono (as I and a few others say in their answers).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with any language that compiles to run on a managed runtime (.NET or Mono CLR, Java JVM) you will need to have that runtime installed. A C# application can compile to run on Windows on the .NET CLR, or on all the platforms you mention to run on the Mono runtime instead. Alternatively, a Java application would compile to run on the Java JRE, which is also compatible with all the platforms you mention.

So with either language there is potentially this extra installation overhead, and with either language you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have .NET installed on your client's system in order to use your application.

As for running cross-platform - depending on how your Application is written, this can be simple or difficult.

You may want to look at Silverlight.  This is directly supported on OS X and works on Linux via Moonlight.

Another alternative is to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to run your .NET application on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

A C# app will need an implementation of the CLR (.NET) running on the local machine in order to run.  A Java app will need an implementation of the JVM so it is really no different.  On Windows, I would expect most people to have a .NET install.

Take a look at the Mono project as far as running it on Linux and Mac:

http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

One thing you can consider is using an older version of the .NET framework to ensure that the greatest number of people have it installed.  I would use .NET 3.5 or even 2.0 if you do not need fancy new features.  That would have been installed already on Windows 7 for example.

Since the Windows 7 user had to download the framework I assume you are currently targeting .NET 4 which means you must be using Visual Studio 2010 (or an express version).  Here is a link that tells you how to target a different version of the framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

One quick note about Mono, it is an excellent cross-platform option but it does not support the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) GUI framework at this point.  You will either have to use Windows Forms or create different front-ends for different platforms.

If you want to create a Linux GUI (also available on Windows and Mac) you can try GTK#:

http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp

For a Mac native GUI you can check out MonoMac:

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/06/09/monomac_in_monodevelop

An excellent IDE for cross-platform .NET development is MonoDevelop (it will read your VC# project files):

http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Thanks Justin for the links, you rock!

Comment: Thanks whydna, I am glad I could help.  Please consider accepting somebody's answer if we were able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Java, .Net languages need a runtime installed. The full .Net framework is sometimes too big for small applications, so there is a smaller version of it call the compact framework with a smaller footprint that will install and download faster. You can read about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx. As noted by other answers most current versions of Windows come with various versions of .Net framework, so this installation may not be needed for every user.

As far as your cross platform needs go Mono allows for running .Net applications on Linux, I am not sure about running them on OSX. My assumption is you can not. Unfortunately your cross platform requirements made .Net a bad choice, and you should have gone with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Other people gave you complicated answers. Well here's my simple answer. .NET framework is needed to run .NET applications and so do Java need JVM (as MCain said). Starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft includes .NET Framework built inside Windows. And in addition, .NET have versions, from 1.0 to 4.0. With Vista and Windows 7, .NET 3.5 is installed by default. I think **your app is targeted for .NET 4.0 which is why a Windows 7 user needed to install .NET framework**. For me, **if I have to write a simple program, I'll use .NET 2.0** (later version = larger libraries, etc) so that my users (if they are Vista or Windows 7) don't have to install .NET again to run my software. You can choose which version of .NET you will target from New Project Window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the target framework in the properties tab. If you start a project in VS2008 the default is .net 3.5 and for VS2010 it is .net 4.0. If you don't need the advanced features you can change your target back to 2.0  which should be available on most computers by now (I would guess far over 90%). Be sure to remove dependencies which are not available in 2.0 (like System.Linq, System.DataSet.Extensions) and the accociated imports (But the compiler will tell you what to do).